# Quartz.net cron trigger expression for every two week

Tags: c#, xml, quartz.net

I need to create cron trigger which runs on Friday in every tow week

```
0 30 17 ? * FRI#2 *
```

is what I managed to create, but the schedule it generates simply runs on every second Friday of month. Is it possible to achieve what I need using `Cron Expression`?

I heard about new trigger type in `quartz.net 2.x` but could not get any good example our to configure it in XML config file. What I mean is **CalendarIntervalTrigger** Can anyone assist me on how to get desired result?

UPDATE

```
            var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("InvoiceGenerator", "InvoiceGenerator")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSchedule(CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder.Create().WithIntervalInWeeks(2)).Build();
```

this is what I managed to create on c# side (no xml unfortunately) but when i call **GetNextFireTimeUtc** on **trigger** it always returns null.

**UPDATE**
Thank your all for your answers what I managed to came up with is to either create normal cron trigger which runs every Friday and in execution check weather tow weeks passed science last run or not.

with c# it is the following code snippet.

```
        var friday = new DateTime(2015, 04, 10, 17, 30, 00);
        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("InvoiceGenerator", "InvoiceGenerator")
                .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInWeeks(2))
                .WithDescription("trigger")
                .StartAt(friday)
                .Build();
        var nexRun = trigger.GetFireTimeAfter(friday);
```

nexRun is correct in this case. 
The only thing left now is to figure out who we can configure it using XML.

Comment: GetNextFireTimeUtc is null until the first time the trigger is fired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly simple to do programmatically with one trigger. I don't think it can be done via a single cron expression.

```
        var friday = new DateTime(2015, 04, 02, 17, 30, 00)
        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("InvoiceGenerator", "InvoiceGenerator")
                .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInWeeks(2))
                .WithDescription("trigger")
                .StartAt(friday) 
                .Build();
```

It seems to me you are using RAMJobStore in which case your triggers are kept in the quartz_jobs.xml file. It is indeed **possible** to set calendar intervals in XML. For example, the above trigger would translate as follows:

```
<trigger>
  <calendar-interval>
    <name>calendarJobName</name>
    <group>calendarJobGroup</group>
    <description>CalendarTriggerDescription</description>
    <job-name>jobName1</job-name>
    <job-group>jobGroup1</job-group>
    <start-time>2015-04-02T17:30:00.0Z</start-time>
    <end-time>2099-04-02T17:30:00.0Z</end-time>
    <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
    <repeat-interval>2</repeat-interval>
    <repeat-interval-unit>Week</repeat-interval-unit>
  </calendar-interval>
</trigger>
```

Comment: The only problem here is that if you write this code after calling GetNextFireTimeUtc() return is always null. I do not know why I simply created Console app and in main method just copied and pasted this code but result is the same again null for GetNextFireTimeUtc() method

Comment: @Rati_Ge **after** calling GetNextFireTimeUtc()? You need to schedule the trigger first and then call the method as explained in the [documentation](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/cc03bb79-c0c4-6d84-3d05-a17f59727c98.htm).

Comment: Is <end-time>2099-04-02T17:30:00.0Z</end-time> mandatory or I can omit this tag so that this runs forever?

Answer (score 2):

This can't be achieved with a cron expression. You can get close by adding three triggers to your Quartz job, although it doesn't meet your requirements for months with five Fridays.

The first trigger should fire every first Friday of the month:

```
0 30 17 ? * FRI#1 *
```

And the second trigger should fire every third Friday of the month

```
0 30 17 ? * FRI#3 *
```

And a third trigger is needed to handle months with a fifth Friday:

```
0 30 17 ? * FRI#5 *
```

This last trigger is not perfect as the next run will be in a week's time.

Alternatively you could create a cron expression that fires every week with the Quartz job checking the last fire time and do nothing if the last fire time is less than 14 days ago.

Comment: Do you mean that on Execution to check last fire time and if DateTime.Today() - Last fire time is less than 14 days do nothing?

Comment: Yes, that might be the easiest way to implement this unless you can get the CalendarIntervalTrigger working.

Comment: This seems to be OK for us at this moment thank you very much could you please provide link for CalendarIntervalTrigger as well?

Comment: I only found this blog on CalendarIntervalTrigger, although it does not provide an actual example: http://jvilalta.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/new-in-quartznet-20the-calendar.html. Please note that the latest Quartz.net release 2.2.3 contains several bug fixes for CalendarIntervalTrigger, so if you can it might be worth updating to this version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating multiple jobs for each Day of the Week, then using the CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder to set the weekly interval. You will have to calculate your next startdate manually though.

E.g.

```
For each DayOfWeek in MyDaysOfWeek
    StartDate = GetNextWeekDay(JobStartDate,DayOfWeek)
    Dim Sched = CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder.Create().WithIntervalInWeeks(Interval).WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()

    Dim JobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity(JobTriggerName).
                            StartAt(StartDate).WithSchedule(Sched).EndAt(EndDate).Build()

     'Add to your scheduler here
next
```